# Let $f:U \to V$ be a bijective holomorphic function. Show that inverse of $f$ is also holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Suppose $U$ and $V$ be domains(i.e., open and connected) in $ \mathbb C$.Let $f\colon U \to V$ be a bijective holomorphic function. Show that the inverse of $f$ is also holomorphic.

By Open Mapping Theorem it is clear that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. Please give some ideas to complete the proof.

**Edit**:I'm interested in a proof which comes as a corollary of  open mapping theorem

Comment: Let $U' = \{ z \in U : f'(z) \neq 0\}$ and $V' = f(U')$. You know $f\lvert_{U'}\colon U' \to V'$ is biholomorphic. What kind of singularity could $f^{-1}$ have in a point $w \in V\setminus V'$?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm sorry.Can you please write it as a solution with some more words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the open mapping theorem, $f$ is a homeomorphism. When $f'(z_0) \neq 0$, the complex differentiability of $f^{-1}$ at $f(z_0)$ follows in the usual way.

Now consider $U' = \{ z\in U : f'(z) \neq 0\}$ and $V' = f(U')$. By the above, $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on $V'$. But since $U\setminus U'$ consists only of isolated points, and $f$ is a homeomorphism, $V\setminus V'$ consists only of isolated points. Thus a $w\in V\setminus V'$ would be an isolated singularity of $f^{-1}$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, it would be a removable singularity. Hence $f^{-1}$ is holomorphic on all of $V$. (And consequently we have $U' = U$.)

Comment: +1..neat solution!If I recall correctly,sometime back I read a solution of this problem on MSE website which just used C-linearity condition of a R linear map.I think that solution was also given by you.But now I 'm unable to find that solution.Regards,

Comment: Dear If you know that solution can you please attach the link?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Learner, I don't remember such an argument, and searching on the site didn't turn up anything either. At the moment, I don't see how such an argument would look.

Comment: Dear, Thank you! I accept your answer,If you recall that argument,don't forget to attach here.Regards,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What happens in a small disk around $z_0\in U$ if $f'(z_0)=0$?

Comment: I see..So we don't need open mapping theorem ! I know that injective and holomorphic function is conformal.Can you please help me in recalling the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Following the hint by Hagen von Eitzen, we can show that, if there is a $z_0$ such that $f'(z_0)=0$, then $f$ is not injective. Consider a small circular path $\gamma$ around $z_0$. By Rouche's theorem, the winding number of $f(\gamma)$ around $f(z_0)$ is the order of the zero $z_0$ of $f(z)-f(z_0)$ which, by inspecting its Taylor series at $z=z_0$, is greater than 1. So $f(\gamma)$ must cross itself somewhere, making $f$ not injective. By contraposition, $f'$ is never 0. Now we have that $f^{-1}(z)$ is holomorphic because it's differentiable and \begin{eqnarray} \frac{df^{-1}(z)}{dz}=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(z))}\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So we don't need Open Mapping Theorem,right?

Comment: I don't think so. However, I want to point out that a proof of the open mapping theorem involves Rouche's theorem, which is also used in my answer.

Comment: I see..but someone told me that there  is a direct proof of this fact with Open Mapping Theorem

Comment: I would like to see one.